# Move image to right

Tags: android

Friends I have an image and I wish to move that image to right side.Please find the necessary code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/error"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
I wish to move the `imageView1` to the right side
Thanks in advance,for the solution

Comment: Then where should the linear layout after the imageview shud be shown??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout for that and use below XML code for solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detail"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/error"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**EDIT:** change ImageView background to `android:background="@drawable/error"`

Comment: android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" change it to android:background="@drawable/error"

Comment: I have already done that.n your code has errors.. shall I keep imageview outside first linearlayout ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Change second Linear layout layout_width="wrap_content"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/error"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```